# Windows 10 - Force Window to Always Be in Focus

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-focus

I have a render utility that when it renders image files it pops up in the background - when it does, I get 1/4 the render speed when it is in the foreground / Active / Focus.

Is there a tool or way to automatically make this window always be the active / focus window?

Always on Top tools don't work because the window isn't active / focus.

Comment: Will you want to still work on other apps, or will you be leaving your computer alone while the render processes?

Comment: Have you tried using Focus Follows Mouse and leaving your mouse pointer over the window? Other than that, I think perhaps an AutoHotKey script that, say, checks every 5 seconds for focus and resets it to the application in question may work.

Comment: This question isn't exactly the same, but it requires the same components, and so the answer should be quite helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901859/how-to-make-window-in-focus-in-autohotkey